# graph cut, cutting at least half the edges

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, greedy

Can anyone help me find a greedy algorithm that find a  cut in a graph with at least half the edges?

I think the right way has something to do with separating vertexes using DFS, but I am not sure.

Comment: Any assumption on the input and output graph?

Comment: the graph is undirected

Comment: According to http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma796s/projects/sahar_report.pdf the problem is `NP`-hard, so most probably there is no suitable greedy algorithm to solve it.

Comment: the cut doesn't have to be maximal.

Comment: Sorry I somewhat misunderstood the question. Note that in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut one can find a sketch of a greedy algorithm with approximation ratio 2 which hopefully solves the problem stated.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 6.3 in Mitzenmacher/Upfal (2005), page 129 gives an algorithm which cuts half of the edges on expectation; like the wikipedia article cited in the above comment says I guess this can be derandomized.